# Add percentage of 'X row' column to SQL pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I've created a SQL pivot and want to add a further calculated percentage column based on the aggregated figures within and I cannot figure out how to make this happen.

Here is the code:

```
Select * from (

Select  
        c_group2 as [Group],
        year(period) as [Year],
        transvalue as [Total],
        from transactions) as s

PIVOT

(       Sum(Total)
        for [Year] in ([2018],[2017],[2016],[2015])) as pvt
```

And this produces the following output:

```
Group | 2018 | 2017 | 2016 | 2015

Sales | 30000| 28000| 25000| 21000

Exp1  | 5000 | 3100 | 3000 | 2500

Exp2  | 600  | 700  | 1000 | 500
```

The additional columns I'd like to include would calculate each expense row (Exp1, Exp2) as a percentage of that year's sales total, giving the following output:

```
Group | 2018 | %   | 2017 | %   | 2016 | %   | 2015 | %

Sales | 30000|     | 28000|     | 25000|     | 21000|

Exp1  | 5000 | 16.6| 3100 | 11.0| 3000 | 12.0| 2500 | 11.9

Exp2  | 600  |  2.0| 700  |  2.5| 1000 |  4.0| 500  |  2.3
```

So effectively for each year, it's Exp1/Sales and then Exp2/Sales and so on as a calculation presumably in the initial sub query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Sales is not the largest amount in the pivoted column then you can either use an inner query like below

```
Select [Group],
 [2018],[2018%]=CASE WHEN Group<>'Sales' THEN 100.00* [2018]/ SUM(CASE WHEN Group='Sales' THEN [2018] END) OVER() END,
 [2017],[2017%]=CASE WHEN Group<>'Sales' THEN 100.00* [2017]/ SUM(CASE WHEN Group='Sales' THEN [2017] END) OVER() END,
 [2016],[2016%]=CASE WHEN Group<>'Sales' THEN 100.00* [2016]/ SUM(CASE WHEN Group='Sales' THEN [2016] END) OVER() END,
 [2015],[2015%]=CASE WHEN Group<>'Sales' THEN 100.00* [2015]/ SUM(CASE WHEN Group='Sales' THEN [2015] END) OVER() END
from (

Select  
        c_group2 as [Group],
        year(period) as [Year],
        transvalue as [Total],
        from transactions) as s

PIVOT

(       Sum(Total)
        for [Year] in ([2018],[2017],[2016],[2015])) as pvt
```

Comment: This appears to assume that the largest (MAX) aggregate value is always the divisor of the [Group].  There is a likelihood that expenses may exceed sales...  How can this be amended to replace: [2018] / MAX([2018]) with [2018] / [Group]='Sales'

Comment: Perfect. Thank you